# XMLHttpRequest always sends as GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I wrote an AJAX js library a while ago (a simple one) and today I suddenly noticed it wasn't working anymore.

Now, I've ripped some of the code out of it and manually put it into a script to test it. Again, it's not working correctly. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why?

This is the javascript code:

Now here, the first one works and the second one doesn't...

```
  $loginBtn.on("click", function() {
    if(validateForm($loginForm))
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", "/login/login/", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");

      var url    = $loginForm.attr('action');
      var params = "username=foo&password=bar";
      var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp2.open('POST', url, true);
      xhttp2.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhttp2.send(params);

    }
    return false;
  });
```

The end goal is to do this with `formData()`, but i'm going back to basics to see what's going wrong here.

The thing is, that even though the XMLHttpRequest DOES fire, it seems to completely ignore everything I set for it.
The headers return as a `GET` while I'm setting it to `POST`, the content-type I set is nowhere to be seen. No matter what header I add, it's not being added.

It just sends a `GET` for no apparent reason. The call in itself is succesful and gives the appropriate response, though.

**things I've tried so far;**

- checked any type of caching and made sure I'm not using cached scripts
- stripped away all extra functions to make sure there is nothing else going wrong
- Made sure there is no server-side caching of any kind
- Disabled all other scripts for testing reasons.

Comment: Are you watching the browser's "Network" developer tool to track the HTTP requests? A common problem is to trigger your XHR from some event that also triggers a form submission. How exactly is the code being invoked?

Comment: Copy/pasting your code sends a `POST` request in chrome/IE11, and an error: `The URI is malformed` in FF. What are you using to test? Where are you seeing that it "just sends a `GET`..."?

Comment: I just pasted this code into the console in my browser and the outgoing method and headers were OK, so this code seems to be in order. I second @Pointy 's comment about form submissions and such. Did you try running nothing but this code? Also, when you debug, make sure you check "Preserve Log" on the "Network" tab, otherwise if the page reloads (e.g. because of a form submission), you won't see the outgoing request.

Comment: @Pointy is probably correct. Currently, I have 2 seperate XHR requests within the same form submission, though 1 somehow works wile the other doesn't. I'm going to update my answer with the full code of it.

Comment: Guys, I think I got it... Could it be that this is the result of a .htaccess redirect? Because I just put an extra / behind the url and it worked... Now I've opened my .htaccess and noticed there's a redirect on any url not ending with /...

Comment: FWIW I've noticed that Edge reports weird apparently "phantom" GET requests after XHRs sometimes. They're marked as being satisfied from cache, which in my case is not possible (the URLs would have failed at the server due to it being a GET).